# How to share static event from static class with multiple threads

Tags: c#, events, thread-safety, static-classes

I am writing a C# Script control (WinForms). This is based on Dockpanelsuite, Scintilla, CSharpScriptingLibrary and a lot of code I wrote/collected in the last year. I want to include a prebuild "Logging" and a "ProgressBar" feature. So far I got everything to work as expected, except the fact it wont work correctly when using Timers.

The code written in the editor is compiled at runtime, the "Programm"-type is loaded and the "Main"-method is invoked. If the created assembly includes a "Log"-type the "LogMessage"-event will be connected to a method in the hosting script control, which forwards the messages to the Output-window.
[image: Script editor]
[image]

As you can see the "Hello World" message is written to the Output-window, but each time the timer fires the LogMessage event in the static Log-Class is null. 
Any idea what I have to change to share the LogMessage event from the UI thread with the Timer thread?

Programm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace ScriptControl
{    
    public class Programm
    {
        Timer timer = null;
        int step = 0, steps = 10;

        public void Main()
        {                   
            Log.Write("Hello World");   
            try
            {
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.Interval = 1000;
                timer.Elapsed += TimerHandler;
                timer.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Write(ex);
            }
        }

        private void TimerHandler(object sender, object args)
        {           
            if(this.step == 1) timer.Enabled = false;           
            Log.Write(step++.ToString());
            Progress.Set(this.step, steps);            
        }
    }
}
```

Log.cs

```
public delegate void LogHandler(object message);
public static class Log
{
    public static event LogHandler LogMessage;

    public static void Write(object message)
    {
        if(LogMessage != null) 
            LogMessage(message);
        else 
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("LogMessage is null"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you subscribed the event with `Log.LogMessage += MyMessageHandler;` somewhere? In winforms you would use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Comment: The event is subscribed in the hosting scripting control via reflection. As you can see the "Hello World" message is passed successfully, so that is not the problem.